# create dynamic route and load template at runtime

Tags: ember.js

I have many page templates into my project and I don't want insert all templates into a single page. 
After the application is started it's possible to add new routers and templetes at runtime ?
example:
I start with Home page then by e service I load one javascript file with route and template for page 2 , is it possible ?

thanks